# Does this Series Converge? and how does it converge/diverge, what method should i use

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series of $$\frac{n!2^n}{n^n}$$ as $n \to \infty$ converge?

I found this question while studying series and sequences and I can't find an answer for it. I tried several criteria but no luck yet. I also have just started learning this material. Maybe that's why I can't quickly detect what criteria fits these type of series. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use Stirling's formula.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you know that $(1 + \frac1n)^n \to e$, use the ratio test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $a_n=\dfrac{n!2^n}{n^n}>0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$. 
If we study the series with the ratio test we have, for $n \to \infty$
$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{(n+1)!2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\dfrac{n^n}{n!2^n}=\dfrac{2{ {(n+1)} }n!2^n}{(n+1)(n+1)^n}\dfrac{n^n}{n!2^n}=2\dfrac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}=$$ $$=2\bigg(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\bigg)^{n}=2\dfrac{1}{\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^n}\longrightarrow_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{2}{e}<1$$
We can conclude that $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent .

Comment: Consider adding the definition of $a_n = \frac{n!2^n}{n^n}$. Took me a moment go get that right.

Comment: thank you I edited my post

Comment: how is it 2/e ? shouldnt it be 2/ 1^n as n gets to infinity?

Comment: It is a notable limit: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n=e$